# JavaScript innerHTML not populating

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to populate a  with data pulled from a database query via an Ajax call. However, the section that I'm trying to populate remains empty. The JS is in a separate file which is imported at the end of the HTML. The function call to populate the  is also at the end, so I know it's not an issue of the ID not existing yet.

Here are the contents of my onreadystatechange function:

```
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
  {
     const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

     cards =  "";
     for (x in data)
     {
        cards +=
           " <!-- Story Card -->\n" +
           "<div class=\"card filterDiv State3\" style=\"width: auto;\">\n" +
           "   <div class=\"card-body\">\n" +
           "      <h5 class=\"card-title\">State 3 Card title</h5>\n" +
           "      <h6 class=\"card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted\">Card subtitle</h6>\n" +
           "      <p class=\"card-text\">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>\n" +
           "   </div>\n" +
           "</div> <!--End Story Card --> \n"
     }
     console.log(cards);
     document.getElementById("left-col").innerHTML = cards;
  }
```

I added the call to console.log to confirm that the PHP file is returning the correct number of results (and a now-deleted alert confirmed that the JSON had all the correct information and no errors), and everything is printing to the console correctly, but the element is not being updated. The  where this goes is:

```
<div id="left-col">
    <!-- To be populated by cards.js -->
</div>
```

The same methodology worked for a different area of the page, so I wasn't expecting any problems with this. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're using "console.log()" - good.  I presume you're using Chrome developer tools (or equivalent) to view the output, correct?  SUGGESTION: Set a breakpoint at `document.getElementById()` and confirm 1) that `cards` looks OK, and 2) that `document.getElementById("left-col")` is actually pointing to the correct element in your DOM.

Comment: Perform a `console.log(document.getElementById("left-col").innerHTML)` after the assignment. If that prints the expected also, then your issue is probably related to CSS that is somehow not revealing the content on the page. Make sure to include the relevant CSS in your question.

Comment: Might something else be overwriting `#left-col`'s `innerHTML`? after the response comes back?

Comment: So I'm a little embarassed now. Following @trincot's suggestion, I find that the div is appropriately populated. It's just not displaying on the screen. I should have thought to check for that.

There's nothing that should prevent it from displaying, though.

Comment: If it's not displaying, then check with the dev console what the current content of the `div` is: right click it on the page and choose `inspect element` or whatever your browser offers to inspect the actual HTML inside that `div`. If also there you see the content, then check the CSS that is applied to that `div` (dev console can help with that too). Make sure there is no styling applied that hides it from view. This can be many things: `display: none`, `visibility: none`, or positioning outside the view or under another element (`z-index`), ...etc, etc.

Comment: With the browser's dev console you can also *alter* the CSS on the live page: so delete one-by-one each CSS-class that is applied directly or indirectly to that `div` or its main child elements until you see the content on the page appear...

Comment: Following the last suggestion helped. The HTML/CSS guy added a bunch of filter stuff that isn't working properly yet.